# Replace a character in a Python DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

The simple dataframe `replace` shown below is not working.
The `NewPhone` column contains the same value as the original column.

```
import pandas as pd
SF = pd.read_csv(r"xxx.csv")
SF['NewPhone'] = SF['Phone'].replace("(",'xxx')
print(SF['NewPhone'])
```

Answer (score 13):

[`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas.Series.replace) looks for exact matches (by default unless you pass `regex=True` but you will need to escape the parentheses - see @piRSquared's answer), you want [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace):

```
SF['NewPhone'] = SF['Phone'].str.replace("(",'xxx')
```

which will replace all occurrences of the passed in string with the new string

Example:

```
In[20]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'phone':['(999)-63266654']})
df

Out[20]: 
            phone
0  (999)-63266654

In[21]:    
df['phone'].str.replace("(",'xxx')

Out[21]: 
0    xxx999)-63266654
Name: phone, dtype: object
```

If we try `replace` then no match occurs:

```
In[22]:
df['phone'].replace("(",'xxx')

Out[22]: 
0    (999)-63266654
Name: phone, dtype: object
```

See @piRSquared's answer for how to get `replace` to work as expected (I don't want to cannibalise his answer)

Answer (score 5):

The [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) method takes a `regex` argument that is `False` by default.  Set it to `True`.  Also, if the string to be replaced is interpreted as a regex pattern, we'll need to escape the opening parenthesis.

```
df.phone.replace("\(", 'xxx', regex=True)

0    xxx999)-63266654
Name: phone, dtype: object
```

---

### Setup from @EdChum

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'phone':['(999)-63266654']})
```

Comment: I still think I prefer your answer.  But it's good to remind people of this option.  It's also available for the `DataFrame` variant.