# How do I replace strings with certain values in them inside a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I have a pandas DataFrame with missread string characters in them (like Ã³ for example) and for categorization porpuses I need to clean them up by replacing those characters with the actual letter.

I've tried to use the following code:

```
df_aux1= df3[df3.MY_COL.str.contains('Ã³')]
```

to isolate it and try to convert it.

Is the replacement on a Dataframe even possible or I'm missing something?

Comment: Your code selects rows which contain the particular character, what code are you using to replace that character? Also you can directly use replace without selecting those rows first. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490540/replace-a-character-in-a-python-dataframe-column)

Comment: You need to use .loc (python 3+) in order to selects parts of your column. And you are assigning a new dataframe which isn't what you want to do. Posted my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should help you (Python 3+):

```
df.loc[df['Column Name'] == 'Value you Want to Change', 'Column Name'] = 'New Value'
```

Essentially what this does it it selects the value you want to change in a specific column in a DataFrameusing [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then replaces it in the DataFrame.